# I'm confused working with JavaScript arrays

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

function change1(y) {
  y[0] = 7;
  y[1] = 8;
  y[2] = 9;
  y[3] = 10;
  y[4] = 11;
  y[5] = 12;
}
change1(x);
console.log(x);

var z = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

function change2(y) {
  y = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
}
change2(z);
console.log(z);
```

Output:

```
7,8,9,10,11,12 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

I am unable to understand in the above code why the `change1()` function can alter the passed array while the `change2()` function cannot.

And why is the line break not working?

Comment: Newline break should work if you were writing to the console. Since you are writing to the document/browser it will interpret it as HTML - try using a html newline `<br>`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`y[..] = ...` is *modifying* an existing object. That change is visible to anything that holds a reference to that object.

`y = ...` assigns an entirely new value to the local `y` variable and discards the previously assigned object reference. That change is not visible outside the function since nothing else has access to the `y` variable.